# Match inputs of two text fields

Tags: regex, sapui5

Scenario: I have two input fields. One of them will accept an input in form which the user will decide. The other field should match the format defined in first field. For example, if the user enters format like  *`anan-xxx`* in the first field..:

- The user is allowed to enter `b1c1-!*>`  in the other field.
- User **cannot** enter `1b1c->!*` because the first character is expected to be an alphabet not number.

So the first field will define a format definition for *`a`* (alphabets), *`n`* (numbers), a placeholder, and  *`x`* (any characters).

What is the easy way to perform this in UI5? I read something related to mask input but I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already guessed, the control [`sap.m.MaskInput`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.MaskInput) can be leveraged for this kind of use case.

Here is a demo:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
  "sap/ui/core/Core",
], async (XMLView, JSONModel, core) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View
      xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
      xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"
      xmlns="sap.m"
      xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
      core:require="{ StringType: 'sap/ui/model/type/String' }"
      height="100%"
    >
      <App>
        <Page showHeader="false">
          <form:SimpleForm
            editable="true"
            layout="ColumnLayout"
          >
            <Label text="Mask"/>
            <Input
              value="{
                path: '/maskValue',
                type: 'StringType',
                constraints: {
                  search: '^$|^[-9ax]+$'
                }
              }"
              placeholder="Example: a9a9-xxx (case sensitive)"
            />
            <Label
              text="Masked Input"
              displayOnly="{= !%{/maskValue}}"
            />
            <MaskInput
              mask="{/maskValue}"
              editable="{= !!%{/maskValue}}"
            >
              <rules>
                <MaskInputRule
                  maskFormatSymbol="x"
                  regex="[^_]"
                />
              </rules>
            </MaskInput>
          </form:SimpleForm>
        </Page>
      </App>
    </mvc:View>`,
    models: new JSONModel(),
  });
  core.getMessageManager().registerObject(control, true);
  control.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified,sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_horizon_dark"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

MaskInput has an aggregation named `<rules>` which awaits *n*-[MaskInputRules](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.m.MaskInputRule).

- sap.m.MaskInput [contains already two default rules](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/d62d229f864f4b6240641a5a081c3ddcceb8afcd/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/MaskEnabler.js#L641-L656):

- `"9"` for `/[0-9]/`
- `"a"` for `/[a-zA-Z]/`

- Additional rule added: `"x"` for any characters excluding the *default* placeholder symbol (`_`). The corresponding regex is `/[^_]/`.

For further references, take a look at ["Writing a regular expression pattern"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Writing_a_regular_expression_pattern).

---

Optionally, you could apply the mask in the second Input only when the first Input has passed its value to the model successfully. For this, you could validate the entry via String [type](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8) with the `search` constraint regex `^$|^[-9ax]+$` which allows..:

- `^$`: empty string
- `|`: or
- `^[-9ax]+$`: from the beginning (`^`) till the end (`+$`), only `-`, `9`, `a`, or `x`.

And finally, let the framework handle [UI Messages](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/a90d93df5a024e8bb18826b699c9aaa7) and ValueState in order to make any invalid inputs visible to the user.